# AS3: Null object reference when attempting to check if it exists?

Tags: actionscript-3, reference, null

I have a weird problem. An Object is being passed to my function, and some parameters are optional, so naturally I would check to see if they are there, and if not, do nothing.

However, I'm getting a null reference error (#1009) when I'm just *checking* it. Here's the sample:

```
public function parseObject(params:Object) {
   if (params.optionalParam)
       trace("Got Optional Parameter!");
}
```

The error is returned on the line with the `if` statement. Changing it to check for null (`if (params.optionalParam == null)`) doesn't work either. The players seems to just give up if an object doesn't exist.

Is there any logical reason for this to happen? Or is it some weird bug that has just surfaced?

Thanks in Advance,
-Esa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your params object is null, then you will get a null reference error when trying to access its' optionalParam property.

Try something like:

```
if (params == null)
{ trace("params is null!"); }
else if (params.optionalParam != null)
{ trace("Got optional parameter!"); }
```

Comment: @Esaevian, meddlingwithfire is right here. Just because you've passed another reference to parseObject() and the parseObject method accepted the argument, doesn't mean it is not null. The reference being passed can be null without throwing an error in the method parameters, but once you explicitly attempt to read that object or a property of it, you're going to get your null exception. You need to ensure it's not null so change your code to (if params != null && params.optionalParam != null).

Comment: Derp. Thanks for that. I actually just didn't realize that there would be cases where params would be null. Looks like I just found some, haha. Thanks! (edit: spelling)

Comment: Wait, I'm still getting the error if I check just params: 
    if (params != null) {
        if (params.optionalParam != null)
            trace("Got optional param!")
    }

I'm still getting the error on the first if statement...That's shouldn't be. (I did check though, params is null)

Comment: Do you get the same result if you use array notation to check your property?

if (params != null)
{
 if (params["optionalParam"] != null)
 { trace("Got optional param!") }
}

Comment: Yes, it's not even getting to the inner if statement. The player stops on "if (params != null)"

Comment: Try changing your argument name to something other than "params."  Maybe "params" is an undocumented reserved word?

Comment: Hm, it seems to be fine now. I'll probably run this though a boatload of tests. Seems weird that the player would be so arbitrary. But I think this is the correct answer, and something glitched out before :/

Comment: Just to add to this thread; `params` is not a reserved keyword in ActionScript, so that shouldn't cause any issues.  Also; when checking for existence, you don't need to explicitly compare against `null`, a simple if (!reference) will suffice (and results in more legible code).